# When using SmartGate in Australia with dual passports, which one do you use?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australia

SmartGate lets you not have to deal with a border agent, and simply use a computer to enter the country.

If you have two active passports, which one are you supposed to present at Smartgate when entering Australia?

Comment: Do you have multiple Australian passports, or an Aussie/Kiwi one and a non-Aussie/Kiwi one?

Comment: I have a non-Aussie (South African) and a Kiwi one.

Comment: I'd suggest you pretend that all references to Aussies in the page you cite apply to Aussie or Kiwi, and go with the Kiwi one on those grounds!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From Australia's Department of Border and Immigration's website](https://www.border.gov.au/FAQs/Pages/what-if-I-hold-dual-or-multiple-passports-when-using-arrivals-SmartGate.aspx):

> **What if I hold dual or multiple passports when using arrivals
>    SmartGate?**
>
> **Non-Australian citizens**
>
> If you are a dual passport holder – aged 16 years or older and hold an
>   ePassport from an eligible country – you can use arrivals SmartGate.
>   At the kiosk, be sure to use the same ePassport you presented when
>   checking in to your flight to Australia.
>
> **Australian citizens**
>
> If you are an Australian citizen, you must use your Australian
>   passport to enter Australia. If you are aged 16 years or older* and
>   hold an Australian ePassport, you can use arrivals SmartGate. At the
>   kiosk, be sure to use your Australian ePassport.
>
> *Australian children aged 10 to 15 years (inclusive) can use arrivals SmartGate if they hold an ePassport and are accompanied by a minimum
>   of two adults.